# Split stringurl in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string

Can anyone help me on this? I Have a string which contains multiple URLs 
How can split these URLs into a `string` array?

```
string urls = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.csvhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1.csvhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask3.csv"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? What did you research (which I assume you've done) on splitting strings reveal? Why isn't it applicable to your situation? Why are your URLs stored as a single string without delimiter?

Comment: That's how get a string from third party service. If there was a delimiter than I would have used Split method.

Comment: ...and what are the answers to my other questions?

Comment: @Axya split using `https://`and prefix every item with https:// again.

Comment: If I split with https:// then I get stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.csv as an output

Comment: Or use Regular expressions. this will help you figure out the right pattern : https://regexr.com/

Comment: Is There any way of splitting after .csv?

Comment: True I can prefix https:// but its not the right solution. I'll look for Regex. Possibly i get something there

Comment: @Axya Yes split it using `.csv` and append every item with `.csv`. Do some exeperiment, don't ask exact answers

Comment: You could use regex like this `(https?://.*?\.csv)`. Or just split on CSV and add back `.csv`

Comment: Yes @John I tried that. I was looking for some  better option. I think I should go with that.

Comment: You should always include in your question what you've already tried, so that we don't waste your time by providing you the same answers.

Comment: @Kaushik, I know there's always work around when you work with the code. I posted this because there are people who come across such situations. That's okay. I'll figure it out

Comment: @John Sure. I'll do that next time. Thank you

Comment: I think you need to say WHY it's not acceptable to you to split on `https://` and then add it back in.. I'm perfectly fine with it as a solution, and it's better than splitting on .csv (could more reasonably occur in other parts of the url where's a the scheme definitely only occurs at the start)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var urlsArray = urls.Split("http").Select(i => "http" + i).ToArray();
```

For completeness, you could use regular expressions:

```
  var urls = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.csvhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1.csvhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask3.csv";
  var urlsArray = Regex.Split(urls, "(?=https?://)").Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).ToArray();
```

Pattern `(?=https?://)` explanation:

it is positive lookahead, which assures that what follows is `http` with optional `s` and `://`.

Comment: What if the URL contains something like `https://www.myhttpwebsite.com`?

Comment: No, compiler error as Split method  take StringSplitOptions as second parameter
 along  with string .

Comment: @Axya It works on mine PC, also see update :)

Comment: @Axya Then you should accept the answer (green check mark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'd be fine with a simple split if they were all https://:

```
var a = urls.Split(new[]{"https://"}, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(url => "https://" + url);
```

But you could use regex, helpful if there is a mix of http/s. The brackets around the regex cause the delimiter to be kept but this produces an array of `{"scheme", "host/path", "scheme", "host/path"}` so a bit of work to stick the schemes back onto the host/paths

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(urlsasstring, @"(https?://)");
string[] urls = new string[result.Length/2];
for(int x = 0, y=0; x < result.Length; x+= 2,y++){
  urls[y] = result[x] + result[x+1];
}
```

Or you could skip through it yourself using indexof and substringing. The nuisance there is that there isn't an IndexOfAny that takes an array of strings (for http / https) but you could do http, then IndexOf  for :// and see if it's 4 or 5 after the first IndexOf, and if not skip on. Each time you find a new valid index, recall the previous index and substring between them. Quite involved I think.. it would probably be easier to do a urlsasstring.Replace to replace http:// with a single char that doesn't appear in a url (tab?) and https:// another char that doesn't appear in a url (newline?) then use IndexOfAny, then convert back as part of the substringing process